# Como fazer um span exibir o valor de um range a medida que movimento ele com o mouse?

Tags: javascript, html, input, range

A função está funcionando, porém quero fazer atualizar o valor no `<span>` a medida que mexo com o mouse. Alguém pode ajudar?

```js
function mostrarPorcentagem(novoValor) {
    document.getElementById("exibePercent").innerHTML = novoValor;
}
```

```html
<input id="percent" type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="0"                                      onchange="mostrarPorcentagem(this.value)"/>
<span id="exibePercent">0</span>
```

Comment: @Renan acredito que seja relacionada, porém a pergunta faz ênfase em outra coisa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize [`oninput`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp) chamando a função:

***Com uma função:***

```js
function mostrarPorcentagem(novoValor) {
  document.getElementById("exibePercent").innerHTML = novoValor;
}
```

```html
<input id="percent" type="range" oninput="mostrarPorcentagem(this.value)"
        min="-100" max="100" value="0" />
<span id="exibePercent">0</span>
```

---

***Sem função:***

```html
<input id="percent" type="range"
       oninput="getElementById('exibePercent').innerHTML = this.value;" 
       min="-100" max="100" value="0" />
<span id="exibePercent">0</span>
```

***Referencias:***

- [oninput Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp)
- [HTML oninput Event Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/ev_oninput.asp)

Comment: Ficou perfeito, obrigado.. Aceitarei assim que o sistema permitir.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer desta forma:

```js
var $range = document.querySelector('input'),
    $value = document.querySelector('span');

$range.addEventListener('input', function() {
  $value.textContent = this.value;
});
```

```html
<input id="percent" type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="0"/>
<span id="exibePercent">0</span>
```